# How to get distinct records based on flag or most recent update timestamp?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, sql-insert, create-table

I am trying to get records based on following conditions.

**Table : store**

**Schema:**

```
create table store (product varchar(50),product_id number,product_type varchar(10),product_flag char(1),product_upd_dt Date);
insert into store(product,product_id,product_type,product_flag,product_upd_dt)values('Apple',123,'GALA','Y','16-MAR-20 06.49.05');
insert into store(product,product_id,product_type,product_flag,product_upd_dt)values('Apple',123,'GALA','N','16-MAR-20 06.49.05');
insert into store(product,product_id,product_type,product_flag,product_upd_dt)values('Apple',134,'JAZZ','N','16-MAR-20 06.49.05');
insert into store(product,product_id,product_type,product_flag,product_upd_dt)values('Apple',134,'JAZZ','N','14-MAR-20 06.49.05');
insert into store(product,product_id,product_type,product_flag,product_upd_dt)values('Apple',134,'JAZZ','N','15-MAR-20 06.49.05');
insert into store(product,product_id,product_type,product_flag,product_upd_dt)values('Apple',13,'ENVY','Y','15-MAR-20 06.49.05');
commit;
```

1)Out of this i want to get product_id based on product_flag='Y'

2)If the product_flag is 'N' then get the most recent updated product_id.

3)One product can mapped to same product_id, but different product_types.

4)Same row can be repeated but difference in product_upd_dt

Here is an example.

Input Image

[image]

Here is the expected Output-

Output Image

[image]

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Which database do you really use? I doubt you use MySQL **and** PostgreSQL **and** Oracle, do you?

Comment: I am using oracle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, 1-4 represent directions, not separate questions ... sorry, I initially misunderstood the problem.

How about this?

```
SQL> select product,
  2    product_id,
  3    product_type,
  4    max(product_flag) product_Flag,
  5    max(product_upd_dt) product_upd_dt
  6  from store
  7  where product_id in (select product_id
  8                       from store
  9                       where product_flag = 'Y'
 10                      )
 11  group by product, product_id, product_type;

PRODUCT    PRODUCT_ID PRODUCT_TY P PRODUCT_UPD_DT
---------- ---------- ---------- - ------------------
Apple             134 ENVY       Y 15-mar-20 06.49.05
Apple             123 GALA       Y 16-mar-20 06.49.05
Apple             134 JAZZ       N 16-mar-20 06.49.05

SQL>
```

Comment: those are data criteria.Sorry for the confusion.I guess you understand it's two separate queries.But this should be achieved in single query.If you look at the output you will have better understanding.

Comment: Right; figured it out after seeing desired output. Have a look at modified query, please.

Comment: it worked partially.I got output with 4 records, when i executed your query.But i see your output have only 3 records.I even got this records also Apple 134 JAZ N 14-MAR-20 06.49.05(Which should be eliminated.)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I got 3 rows as a result, and they match your desired output. What "4 records" are you talking about?

Comment: What changed? Except that the last row's ID = 13 (while it should be 134, according to the 1st screenshot you posted)?

Comment: Yes, it works regardless change you made. You're welcome.

Comment: How this query is returning even 'N' records?